# How to represent NSData in ImageView in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm new in android. I have ArrayList with objects NSData that have image inside and I want to show that list of images in my application. How can I solve this problem? Here is a library that I use http://codenav.org/code.html?project=/org/robovm/robovm-cocoatouch/0.0.14&path=/Source%20Packages/org.robovm.apple.passkit/PKPass.java#tabs2-1
Code of method that create ArrayList with icons is

```
 public ArrayList<NSData> getIconps ()throws NSErrorException {
        for (int i=0;i<pass2.size();i++){
            icon.add(new PKPass(pass2.get(i)).getIcon().toPNGData());
        }
        return icon;
```

How can I show that icon in ImageView?

Comment: RoboVM has been discontinued in Apr. 2016. Do you really use this?

Comment: Yes I'm using it. Maybe you know better library for handling with pkpass file ? If so please let me know.

Comment: Did you tried PassKit? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpass